# Restricting Access to pages via Identity 2.0 and web forms MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web-config, asp.net-identity

I am trying to restrict certain pages to only certain Roles within my ASP.NET WebForms MVC. I have tried implementing some of the Web.config solutions I've seen about Identity 2.0, but I am having no luck at all.

I've moved some of the User / Roles management stuff to the controller-side, and I have 3 Roles for admin function - `SuperUsers`, `InstituteAdmins`, and `AccountAdmins`. I can add users to roles, and I can see the roles and users in SQL Studio, but I really am stuck as to where to implement the restricted access. I have tried this in the web.config file:

```
<!--roles-->
    <!-- Allow all "SuperUsers" role users to access ManageCategory.aspx -->    
     <location path="ManageCategory.aspx">    
          <system.web>    
               <authorization>    
                    <allow roles="SuperUsers" />
                    <deny users="*"/> 
               </authorization>    
          </system.web>   
     </location>
```

But this doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why use `web.config` (for MVC)? You can use the `AuthorizeAttribute` for that, as described [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: 1) Are you sure the role is "SuperUsers" and not "SuperUser"? 2) Is "ManageCategory.aspx" at the same level as the Web.config?

Comment: Yes, it is SuperUsers.

Comment: I should clarify, I set up my own MVC system through web forms, as I've been taught, so I've added in OWIN and just now web API 2.0. I feel like I am missing a step to configuring all of this, even with the authorize attribute in my controller I have access to all pages outside the roles specified. Is there another step beyond adding the packages and using the api on my controller class?